# twisted handle connection lost

Tags: python, twisted

I've try to create a ldap proxy application using [ldaptor proxybase](https://github.com/twisted/ldaptor/blob/master/docs/source/cookbook/ldap-proxy.rst) and Twisted.
The proxy application handle connection request from client(C) -> proxy(P) -> LDAPserver(S)

My problem is once the connection between P -> S was close and connection between C -> P still open, if client send a ldap request, the proxy return error.

So I've try to handle the connection lost event in P -> S, and trigger a method and close the connection between C -> P

Here is my code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

class LoggingProxy(ProxyBase):
    """
    A simple example of using `ProxyBase` to log requests and responses.
    """
    def handleProxiedResponse(self, response, request, controls):
        """
        Log the representation of the responses received.
        """
        log.msg("Request => " + repr(request))
        log.msg("Response => " + repr(response))
        return defer.succeed(response)
        
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.client is not None and self.client.connected:
            if not self.unbound:
                self.client.unbind()
                self.unbound = True
            else:
                self.client.transport.loseConnection()
        self.client = None
        ldapserver.BaseLDAPServer.connectionLost(self, reason)
        log.msg("C -> P CONN LOST: {} {}".format(
            *tcp_lost_conn_repr(self.transport)))
    def connectionClose(self):
        log.msg("C -> P CONN LOST: {} {}".format(
            *tcp_lost_conn_repr(self.transport)))
        self.transport.loseConnection()
    
class MyLDAPClient(LDAPClient):
    """An LDAP client that connect to the proxied server."""
    def connectionLost(self, reason=protocol.connectionDone):
        """Called when TCP connection has been lost"""
        self.connected = 0
        log.msg("P -> S CONN LOST: {} {}".format(
            *tcp_lost_conn_repr(self.transport)))
        while self.onwire:
            k, v = self.onwire.popitem()
            d, _, _, _ = v
            d.errback(reason)
        # Terminate C -> P connection
        LoggingProxy.connectionClose(self)

class LoggingProxyService(Service):
    endpointStr = "tcp:port=10389"
    proxiedEndpointStr = 'tcp:host=localhost:port=389'
    debug = True
    
    def startService(self):
        factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
        use_tls = False
 
        #proxiedEndpointStr = 'tcp:host=localhost:port=389'
        clientConnector = partial(
            connectToLDAPEndpoint,
            reactor,
            self.proxiedEndpointStr,
            MyLDAPClient)

        def buildProtocol():
            proto = LoggingProxy()
            proto.clientConnector = clientConnector
            proto.use_tls = use_tls
            return proto

        factory.protocol = buildProtocol
        ep = serverFromString(reactor, self.endpointStr)
        d = ep.listen(factory)
        d.addCallback(self.setListeningPort)
        d.addErrback(log.err)
        
    def setListeningPort(self, port):
        self.port_ = port

    def stopService(self):
        # If there are asynchronous cleanup tasks that need to
        # be performed, add deferreds for them to `async_tasks`.
        async_tasks = []
        if self.port_ is not None:
            async_tasks.append(self.port_.stopListening())
        if len(async_tasks) > 0:
            return defer.DeferredList(async_tasks, consumeErrors=True)


application = Application("Logging LDAP Proxy")
service = LoggingProxyService()
service.setServiceParent(application)
```

The problem is `LoggingProxy.connectionClose(self)` dose not refer to original instance that initiate the connection.

How could I point to the original `LoggingProxy()` instance and close the connection?

Answer (score 0):

In your `LoggingProxy.connectionLost`, you don't always close the `C -> P` connection:

```
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.client is not None and self.client.connected:
            if not self.unbound:
                self.client.unbind()
                self.unbound = True
            else:
                self.client.transport.loseConnection()
        self.client = None
        ldapserver.BaseLDAPServer.connectionLost(self, reason)
        log.msg("C -> P CONN LOST: {} {}".format(
            *tcp_lost_conn_repr(self.transport)))
```

If `not self.unbound` then `self.client.transport.loseConnection` is never called.  Instead, `self.client` is thrown away so it can never be called.

Try harder to always call `loseConnection` in response to `connectionLost`.